# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am trying to get a scrapy spider working, but there seems to be a problem with SgmlLinkExtractor.

Here is the signature:

> SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=(), allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(), restrict_xpaths(), tags=('a', 'area'), attrs=('href'), canonicalize=True, unique=True, process_value=None)

I am using the allow() option, here is my code:

```
start_urls = ['http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com']
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'series-\d{1}-episode-\d{2}.']), callback='parse_item')]
```

A sample url looks like http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-1-episode-11-the-pancake-batter-anomaly/

the output of `scrapy crawl tbbt` contains

> [tbbt] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-3-episode-17-the-precious-fragmentation/> (referer: http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com)

The parse_item callback, however, is not called and I can not figure out why.

This is the whole spider code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class TbbtSpider(CrawlSpider):
    #print '\n TbbtSpider \n'
    name = 'tbbt'
    start_urls = ['http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com'] # urls from which the spider will start crawling
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'series-\d{1}-episode-\d{2}.']), callback='parse_item')]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        print '\n parse_blogpost \n'
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = TbbtItem()
        # Extract title
        item['title'] = hxs.select('//div[@id="post-5"]/div/p/span/text()').extract() # XPath selector for title
        return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the reason this code is not working is because the syntax of your rule is incorrect.I fixed the syntax without making any other changes and I was able to hit the `parse_item` callback.

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'series-\d{1}-episode-\d{2}.',),
        ), 
        callback='parse_item'),
    )
```

However the titles were all blank which suggests that the `hxs.select` statement in `parse_item` is incorrect. The following xpath may be more suitable (I made an educated gues about the required title, but I could be barking up the wrong tree entirely)

```
item['title'] = hxs.select('//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Changing the rule syntax did not work for me somehow. I am using scrapy version 0.16.4. According to the [scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/overview.html#write-a-spider-to-extract-the-data) the syntax of the rule I used above seems not to be wrong I think.

Comment: I just found the problem. I did not indent the parse_item function properly. Thanks for your help.